# how to display a different image in the DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

In a DataTemplate of a ListView I have this code

```
<Image Grid.Column = "1" Grid.ColumnSpan = "2" Grid.Row = "0" Source = "{Binding Picture}" VerticalAlignment = "center" />
```

I'm a Binding with the Picture property. This property is a string with an address to an image on the web. How can I display an image that I have in the project in the absence of an internet connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick way is to subscribe to the `ImageFailed` event:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Picture}" ImageFailed="ImageFailed" />
```

Then, in the event handler, change the `Source` property to your local picture:

```
private void ImageFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((Image)sender).Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/WideLogo.scale-240.png"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.source.aspx) link states there is a `Image.ImageFailed` event. You can set another source in its handler.

Alternatively, you can check the internet connection in your viewmodel code and set Picture value to something like `"ms-appx:///Assets/image_name.png"`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the use case (like showing images in a GridView where you know the destination image size), another option is to always show a default image and then if and when the correct image is downloaded, it will show on top of the default image.

Just list two images and the second one will show on top of the first.

```
<Grid>
   <Image Source="{Binding DefaultPicture}" />
   <Image Source="{Binding Picture}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: The main issue with that solution is the waste of memory. It may or may not be a problem depending on how heavy the application is

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use converters.Simply use IValueConverter and HttpClient to check if file exists in internet.If HttpClient fails , return your local image URL.